# Javascript validate number commas and decimal

Tags: javascript

I want to return the number true if it is a valid number that contains only digits with properly placed decimals and commas, otherwise return the number false. For example: if number is 1,093,222.04 or 0.232567 then my program should return the number true, but if the input were 1,093,22.04 then my program should return the number false.
For example:

```
input: 1,093,222.04 => true
input: 0.232567 => true
input: 1267 => true
input: 1,093,22.04 => FALSE
input: 1.282,04 => FALSE
input: abcd124 => FALSE
```

I tried this but 1,093,222.04 returns false. It should return true

```
function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean when you say *input may contain characters other than digits*? Can it contain `characters`, or `$`, "%"?

Comment: @decpk It should return false when input is not a number (string, contains characters etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using regex instead

```js
const isNumber = x => !!`${x}`.match(/^\d*(,\d{3})*(\.\d*)?$/)

console.log(isNumber("1,093,222.04")) // true
console.log(isNumber("0.232567")) // true
console.log(isNumber("1267")) // true
console.log(isNumber("1,093,22.04")) // false
console.log(isNumber("1.282,04")) // false
console.log(isNumber("abcd124")) // false
```

Do note that the function must take in a string, since if you pass in the number itself, the commas `,` will split the "number" into different parameters

Comment: I like the use of regex to solve this problem! This might be a good place for `.test` instead of `.match`, i.e. `/^\d*(,\d{3})*(\.\d*)?$/.test(x)`. This is a good start to a solution but it will also return true for numbers that start with a comma, and numbers that do not have a comma where they should. i.e. `,343,343 == true` ; `123123123123,303 == true`

Answer (score 0):

I first create a helper function to parse strings into a float. I use a regular expression to remove all characters that are not a period or digit, then I use parse float to turn it from a string into a float.

I have a function to compare test whether or not the string is properly formatted. I first convert the string to a float, then I format the float as the proper locale string. If the correctly formatted string and the string given are both the same, then I return true, otherwise I return false.

**EDIT**

I added some validation for long decimals, however this example is in no way meant to be a complete solution, just pointing you in the right direction. Depending on your use case you may need more validation or conditions for passing strings. i.e. this example will show `.023` as invalid, because the locale string is properly `0.023`. With this demo you should be able to add more validation as needed

```js
const sToFloat = s => parseFloat(s.replace(/[^\d.]/g, ""));
function goodStringFormat(str) {
  let nOfDecimals = 0;
  if (str.includes(".")) nOfDecimals = str.split(".")[1].length;
  const float = sToFloat(str);
  const formatted = float.toLocaleString(undefined, {maximumFractionDigits: nOfDecimals});
  if (formatted === str) return true;
  return false;
}


console.log(`
  Testing 1,093,22.04
  good? ${goodStringFormat("1,093,22.04")}
  
  Testing 0.02123123123
  good? ${goodStringFormat("0.02123123123")}
  
  Testing 1,093,222.04
  good? ${goodStringFormat("1,093,222.04")}
  
  Testing 1231231,093,222.04
  good? ${goodStringFormat("1231231,093,222.04")}
  
`);
```

Comment: 0.232567 returns false

Comment: also 1,093,222.04 returns false

Comment: while `1,093,222.04` returns true as expected, `0.232567` returns false because `.toLocaleString` by default only has so many decimals. If you wanted to add support for more options you would need to add more validation. I do like the regex option for solving this as well.

Comment: @kutaykurt I added support for long decimals as an example of how you could add further validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the ',' and `input.replaceAll(',','')` and then do the validation, but you need to have your formatter function after all the check